# authentication via django social auth and tastypie for a backbone application

Tags: django, backbone.js, oauth-2.0, tastypie, django-authentication

I am using client side MVC, which reduces my server to be an API. I use [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) for the API. When I did not have the trouble of calling the api, [django-social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) did the trick for me. How do I handle social login/registeration with tastypie?

Comment: Do you want to integrate django-social auth with tastypie? I guess you could extend the Authentication class in tastypie to include  it.

Comment: Your title says djagno, btw :)
Fix it.

Comment: @Pramod yes, i want to keep things dry, and dont want to repeat what has already been done in social auth, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: @whatf Does this help? http://pastebin.com/Bics0QMb

Comment: @Pramod when you look here https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/app/models.py how do i achieve authentication via tasty pie there?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but for others who are interested I'd suggest looking at [django-tastypie-ext](https://github.com/adamhadani/django-tastypie-ext), which has an excellent sample login/reg Authentication class that uses [django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook).  Supporting additional Oauth providers should be similar to the example.